# Gap leaderboard score and model scoring on a Competition

Tags: machine-learning, python

I'm working on a Veolia challenge on Ens Data Challenge [ens-data](https://challengedata.ens.fr/en/home) (equivalent to Kaggle) the goal is to classify very rare binary events (the failure of a pipeline ) for 2014 and 2015 (y={2014,2015}). In input we have 5 features 3 categorical features (which I turned into dummy variable) and two continuous. The score is average AUC, $0.6*AUC_1 + 0.4*AUC_2$.

My problem is the following, when I compute each AUC (for 2014 and 2015) with a stratified kfold cross validation and I compute the average AUC I get roughly 0.88 and when I submit on the website I end up with 0.67, I guess there is a problem in my code.

Here is my code for choosing the best model for 2014:

Rk: to predict on the test set (2014,2015 unknown), I first predict with all 5 features, 2014. Then I add the prediction of 2014 to my feature to predict 2015

```
# Spot Check Algorithms
models = []
models.append(('LG', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('RF', RandomForestClassifier()))
models.append(('GBC', GradientBoostingClassifier()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []

# stratifiedkfold is defined by default when there is an integer
scoring = 'roc_auc'
num_folds = 10

for name, model in models:
    cv_results = cross_validation.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=num_folds, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Comment: You mean you have a model scoring 0.88 while the leaderboard(the score on the website) shows 0.67?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Your test data(the 0.88 one) is different from the test data on the website(the 0.67 one). There must be some difference between their scores. Are you concerning about over-fitting?

Comment: kfold cross validation is not supposed to downsize the overfitting ?

Comment: Can you add your score on training set to your question, that's crucial.

Answer (score 1):

As you have commented, you are concerning about over-fitting.

In fact, cross validation will help to weaken over-fitting, but it can't eliminate over-fitting. Model scoring on TRAIN dataset sometimes exceeds scoring on TEST dataset. Here are some examples I can find:

1. [Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf) (the famous ResNet paper). Checkout figure.1
2. This [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/two-sigma-financial-modeling/univariate-analysis-regression-lb-0-006) of [Two Sigma Financial Modeling Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-modeling) on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) says:

> we are getting a public score of 0.0169 which is slightly better than the previous one.
>   Submitting this model to the LB gave me a score of 0.006

In my practice, I am more willing to concern the scoring gap between TRAIN, VALIDATION(DEVELOP) and TEST dataset. Personally speaking, TRAIN>VALIDATION=TEST is better than TRAIN=VALIDATION>TEST.

Edit: For class imbalance problem, there are some resources:

1. [8 Tactics to Combat Imbalanced Classes in Your Machine Learning Dataset](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/). This blog shows a common workflow dealing with imbalanced class issue.
2. [Class Imbalance Problem in Data Mining: Review](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/). This paper compares several algorithms created for solving the class imbalance problem.

Comment: On the training I get 0.847700964724 AUC and on the validation set LG: 0.909566 (0.032773). With LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')

Comment: I think the problem is that my class are really imbalance I have 0.19% of failure in class 2014